# What is the best fit for this data?

Tags: fitting

First I entered the data and graph it, then I used the non-linear adjustment command to have a model of my data, I asked Mathematica for the square r, to know how good the model was, then I put together the graphs of the data and the adjustment , but I'm not satisfied with the result.
I think it can be improved.
Thank you.

```
DATA = {{16, 2508}, {18, 2518}, {20, 3000}, {22, 3423}, {24, 
3507}, {26, 3400}, {28, 3500}, {30, 3883}, {32, 3823}, {34, 
3646}, {36, 3708}, {38, 3333}, {40, 3517}, {42, 3214}, {44, 
3103}, {46, 2276}};
gt = ListPlot[DATA]
agt = NonlinearModelFit[DATA, b x^a, {a, b}, x]
Show[ListPlot[DATA, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[agt[x], {x, 0, 45}]]
```

[image: This is my code]

[image]

Comment: If you do not provide code that can easily be copied by other people, you are much less likely to get any help on your problem.

Comment: I added it, thanks.

Comment: Is there a process that generates the data that would suggest a particular model (such as the one you tried)?

Comment: This is the description of the problem.
An article by J.Agricultural En.Research, 1975 (pp.353-361) reports the following data (DATA), with the number of days after flowering (D), and harvest yield (R) :
(D) and (R) are the data inside the "DATA" input

Comment: I do not have any particular suggested model, I just looked for one that fits the data.

Comment: How about a simple quadratic? $a x^2 + b x + c$

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[a, b, c, f, x]

data = {{16, 2508}, {18, 2518}, {20, 3000}, {22, 3423}, {24, 
    3507}, {26, 3400}, {28, 3500}, {30, 3883}, {32, 3823}, {34, 
    3646}, {36, 3708}, {38, 3333}, {40, 3517}, {42, 3214}, {44, 
    3103}, {46, 2276}};
```

As suggested by wxffles

```
model = a*x^2 + b*x + c;

f[x_] = (nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c}, x]) // Normal

(* -1945.07 + 362.23 x - 5.74724 x^2 *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 14, 49},
 PlotRange -> {2000, 4000},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]